# Dados somem ao clicar no botão voltar

Tags: javascript, angular

tenho uma aplicação em `Angular 2` onde possuo algumas telas de inserção de dados (`inputs`).
Quando o usuário digita as infos e clica para avançar, ao clicar no botão voltar, as informações somem.
Tentei fazer algo em `LocalStorage` para persistir estes dados:

```
PersisteDados() {
    this.LocalStorageService.get('addons');
    this.LocalStorageService.get('contador');
  }
```

E o chamei no `onInit()` para que carregasse quando a `view` iniciasse, mas não rolou.
Qual seria a melhor forma de se fazer essa persistência?

Answer (score 0):

Use `resolve` é basicamente um condição a ser cumprida antes da view ser carregada, em `angular`, exemplo da documentação

```
class Backend {
  fetchTeam(id: string) {
    return 'someTeam';
  }
}

@Injectable()
class TeamResolver implements Resolve<Team> {
  constructor(private backend: Backend) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.backend.fetchTeam(route.params.id);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        resolve: {
          team: TeamResolver
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [TeamResolver]
})
class AppModule {}
```

em `angularjs` [Resolve angular 1](https://thinkster.io/egghead/resolve)